# How to set Vairable to 0 on Only first open

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there a way for me to set a integer variable to 0, but it will only do this on the first time the app is opened by a device?

Comment: yes, store in the preferences of the app

Comment: What should this variable be initialized to on subsequent startups?

Comment: It should be what it was when they last we on the app. It is a "points" variable. I want it to be set to zero first time without it setting it to zero everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shared preference. Query the shared preference int value (for example) at the start of the application. If it's a first time boot up we get the default 0 value where we change the shared preference value which helps us keep track that it isn't a first time start in the future start of the application.

```
SharedPreferences pref = 
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

In your splash (or wherever necessary) check for a specific key of the shared preference like this :

```
//Check for the key "tracker", if it does not exist consider the default value as 0
int appStartTracker = pref.getInt("tracker", 0);
if(appStartTracker == 0){
    // It means you started the app for the first time. Do what you have to
    // and set the preference to 1 or increment the appStartTracker to keep 
    //track of how many times the app has been started.
    appStartTracker++;
    editor.putInt("tracker", appStartTracker); 
    editor.commit(); 
}else{
    // Not a first time start.
    //Do the following if you need to keep track of total app starts else ignore
    appStartTracker++;
    editor.putInt("tracker", appStartTracker); 
    editor.commit(); 
    Log.d("TAG", "App has been started for the " + appStartTracker +"time");
}
```

P.S The shared preference is cleared when the user clears data.